# Cannot install libboost-all-dev because dependencies are not getting installed

Tags: apt

I am trying to install `libboost-all-dev` but I am getting

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-date-time-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-filesystem-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-iostreams-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-log-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-system-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-thread-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-wave-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've already tried to set the `-f` flag

```
sudo apt-get -f install libboost-all-dev
```

without success. I have no idea what the problem is here.

Comment: Have you tried purging (`apt-get purge libboost-all-dev`) And installing again(`apt-get install -f libboost-all-dev`)?

Comment: @ADDB Not yet but after doing that it only told me that it is not installed thus it's not getting removed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

for keeping your Packages up-to-date. Try

```
sudo apt-get purge libboost-all-dev
```

for deleting the package with all attached files and then use

```
sudo apt-get install -f libboost-all-dev
```

For installing all again.